# Can't resolve chef external cookbook dependency in local mode

Tags: chef, chef-zero

I'm making my first recipes in chef. I created a cookbook i called common with just one recipe (default.rb):

```
apt_repository "mariadb-repo" do
  uri "http://tedeco.fi.upm.es/mirror/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu"
  distribution "trusty"
  components ["main"]
  arch "amd64"
  keyserver "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
  key "CBCB082A"
end
```

I added "depends 'apt'" at the end of my metadata.rb. If i run:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.5.1
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["common"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: apt

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* common


Running handlers:
[2016-01-28T13:07:17+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-01-28T13:07:17+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2016-01-28T13:07:17+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/vagrant/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-01-28T13:07:17+00:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2016-01-28T13:07:17+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Ok, so i added to my Berksfile:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'apt'

metadata
```

Then tried installing apt cookbook to several locations:

```
$ berks install # installs to ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/
$ berks vendor --except=common berks-cookbooks/
```

First thing i notice is that the second command packages both cookbooks, apt and my common, to the directory i specify (even passing --except=common). Nevermind: If i now try to run:

```
$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[common]'
```

From my cookbook's (the one i called common) directory AND from the berks-cookbooks directory. None of both worked, the error above persist. I tried also with the following client.rb at my cookbook's directory:

```
cookbook_path = "./berks-cookbooks"
chef_repo_path = "#{cookbook_path}"
```

And some variations of these...

What am i missing? What's the way to get those dependencies correctly satisfied with chef-client in local mode?

What's the way of satisfying that dependencies?

'''EDIT 1''': Running without sudo does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chef client in local mode reads `knife.rb` as its config file, not `client.rb`. This makes sense when using it on a workstation with things like chef-provisioning, but can be quite unexpected when you are trying to use local-mode in production.

In general with local-mode you should use `berks vendor` to handle the export. Rather than running `chef-client` from the cookbook(s) folder, make a `/root/local_mode_repo` or similar, and run `berks vendor /root/local_mode_repo/cookbooks`. Then you can run `chef-client --local-mode` inside that folder. The specific folder names within the repo like `roles/` and `cookbooks/` are generally not configurable.

Answer (score 2):

For local development, chef-client local-mode looks for `config.rb` or `knife.rb`, starting in the following order `$KNIFE_HOME`, `$PWD`, `.chef/`, and finally `$HOME/.chef/`*.

- **source:** `lib/chef-config/workstation_config_loader.rb` in `chef-config-13.8.5` gem called from `load_config_file()` method from `client.rb`in `chef-13.8.5` gem

In your `config.rb` or `knife.rb`, you want your cookbooks_path to include both location of your *cookbooks* and  *berks_cookbooks*:

```
cookbook_path = ["./cookbooks", "./berks-cookbooks"]
```

One trick I used scoop up all the dependencies is a small shell script that creates a `Berksfile` and then creates the `berks-cookbooks` directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat <<-EOF > Berksfile
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
$(grep -Rh 'depends' cookbooks/* | sed 's/depends/cookbook/')
EOF

berks vendor
berks install
```

Note that `berks install` will install the external cookbooks into your Chef Server so they are available to remote nodes, while `berks vendor` is what you can use for local development with the `berks-cookbooks`.

One tip, I keep my local dev one level up, and my `chef-repo/.chef` to have config for chef server:

```
    .
    ├── .chef
    │   └── knife.rb
    ├── my-chef-repo
    │   ├── berks-cookbooks
    │   ├── .chef
    │   │   └── knife.rb
    │   ├── cookbooks
    │   ├── data_bags
    │   ├── environments
    │   ├── nodes
    │   └── roles
    └── .vagrant
        └── machines
```